# How best to make PHP static variables not to loose data

Tags: php

I thought PHP static variables are not tied to instances. But I am getting an unexpected behaviour

I have the following

```
<?php

class Database
{
    public static $usersdb = array();
    public static $refDb = array();
}
```

I Updated the usersdb and refdb from another php file as below

```
<?php
....
function createPaymentRef($username, $password, $amount)
{
    $finalResult = array();
    $ref = generateTimedTransactionRef($username, $password, $amount);
    global $requestData;
    global $ip;
    unset(Database::$usersdb[$username]);
    $requestData->ip = $ip;
    $requestData->reference = $ref;
    Database::$usersdb[$username] = json_encode($requestData); //Updated
    Database::$refDb[$ref] = json_encode($requestData); //Updated
    $finalResult['result'] = $ref;
    return $finalResult;
}
?>
```

Now, after updating the arrays from the above php file I tried to access the Database from another php file as below

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
....
print_r(Database::$usersdb); //The array is surprisingly empty
print_r(Database::$refDb); //The array is surprisingly empty
?>
```

As I do not want to connect to a real database for this operation How can I resolve this?

Comment: You don't show where you call `Database::createPaymentRef()`. If it isn't called, those values are never populated. Remember, PHP is stateless. Those values are lost once that script stops executing. They aren't stored forever.

Comment: @John Conde It was called in a file `ref.php` and they were really populated. Because I printed the arrays immediately I updated them and I saw very clearly that they were updated. But they all of a sudden they become empty from another php file

Comment: Can't reproduce. Unless you are calling from another request, and then as John Conde says, PHP is stateless.

Comment: Those values are not saved in the file, they are part of that database object. You need to pass that object to another file.